# Partition by, dense rank

Tags: mysql, sql, presto

I have the following table describing patients visits: Each patient has a visit_id for which he sees a given physician. I am trying to extract the value of the visit_id for which saw his 3rd physician. (3rd physician and not 3rd visit)

| patient | visit_id | physician |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | id_1 |
| a | 2 | id_2 |
| a | 3 | id_1 |
| a | 4 | id_3 |
| b | 5 | id_1 |
| b | 6 | id_2 |
| c | 7 | id_1 |
| c | 8 | id_2 |
| c | 9 | id_3 |

so the result would be:

| patient | visit_id |
| --- | --- |
| a | 4 |
| c | 9 |

Any suggestions?

Comment: What problem are you having with dense rank?

Comment: [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=595a28cb601139d6b4fd26cef75084b3) for those interested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following statement returns your result. The innermost subquery eliminates multiple visits to the same physician, then `row_number()` counts the visits and the outermost `select` gets the third physician.

```
select patient, visit 
  from (select patient, visit, row_number() over (partition by patient order by visit) rn
          from  (  select patient, min(visit) as visit 
                     from tab 
                 group by patient, physician
                ) t1
       ) t2
 where t2.rn = 3
```

Result:

| patient | visit_id |
| --- | --- |
| a | 4 |
| c | 9 |

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=de804b9716835cbc7ca086e7a40bdcee)

Answer (score 1):

You can group by `patient` and `physician` to remove "duplicate" physicians and use `min` for `visit_id`:

```sql
-- test data
WITH dataset (patient, visit_id, physician) AS (
    VALUES ('a', 1, 'id_1'),
        ('a', 2, 'id_2'),
        ('a', 3, 'id_1'),
        ('a', 4, 'id_3'),
        ('b', 5, 'id_1'),
        ('b', 6, 'id_2'),
        ('c', 7, 'id_1'),
        ('c', 8, 'id_2'),
        ('c', 9, 'id_3')
)

-- query
select patient, visit_id
from (
        select *,
            row_number() over (partition by patient order by visit_id) rnk
        from (
                select patient,
                    min(visit_id) visit_id,
                    physician
                from dataset
                group by patient, physician
            )
    )
where rnk = 3
```

Output:

| patient | visit_id |
| --- | --- |
| a | 4 |
| c | 9 |

Note that this query uses presto syntax (as your question has presto tag).